# Django migrations- "no such table"

Tags: django

I recently tried to remove a few models for upvoting/downvoting posts by manually dropping the tables for the models in SQLite. This worked fine, except for now when I go to migrate after removing the models for the tables, Django raises a "no such table" error for the deleted tables. What can I do about this?

Comment: Did you remove the models then went to manually drop the database tables? because this is not how migrations work. you should just remove it from the models then migrate. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I dropped the tables before I removed the models.

Comment: You should not change the database manually, but use `makemigrations` and then `migrate`, also to remove models/tables. If the only change you made was to remove the models (and thus your db is in sync with your models), you can run `manage.py migrate --fake` once to just let django know the operations in the migration are already applied to your db. But this is really not the recommended way, since `--fake` can be causing quite some issues if not done properly. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake)

Comment: @dirkgroten worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

By deleting the tables manually, you've broken the sync between the db and the migrations. The best way to get out of this is probably to delete both your migrations and the db file itself, then rerun createmigrations.

Comment: Found my way out of the hole- just ran a fake migration and all was solved. Thank you for your advice, though. Have a blessed day.

Comment: @vwkjdbdj how do you run a fake migration in django?